# Neo4j: finding if an edge exists between two nodes with an attribute using the Java API (without cypher or gremlin)

Tags: neo4j

I have two nodes in neo4j say:

```
Node start = // set to some node;
Node end = // set to some other node;
```

And, I want to find if there is an edge between them that have the attribute key, "name" with val = "bubba".

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks.

Notes:

1. Do not use Gremlin
2. Do not use Cypher
3. Use only Java API

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't got those relationship indexed in a manual index, just figure out which of the two nodes has got the least relationships of the type(s) you're looking for and iterate over those to see if the node on the other side of that relationship is the expected one and the relationship has got that property (check in that order since "other node" check is cheaper than property lookup).

Comment: MMm, so at a high level I was thing to use the traversal API with Evaluators to filter - but this seems awfully complex for such a simple task